# How to filter JSON data with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 so not sure if I am going about this in the correct way.

I have a JSON object of posts.

```
{
  "title": "title one",
  "category": ["dogs","cats","pets"]
},
{
  "title": "title two",
  "category": ["gold fish", "pets"]
}
```

I would like to get all the categories from the posts

```
["dogs","cats","gold fish", "pets"]
```

Comment: "I have a JSON object of posts " — That isn't a JSON object. It's just invalid.

Comment: use javascript .map() function

Comment: "not sure if I am going about this in the correct way" — You aren't going about it in any way at the moment.

Comment: use lodash [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) method.

Comment: You need to (a) make an effort and (b) Ask a more specific question. What probablem are you actually having? Writing JSON in the first place? Getting the JSON into JavaScript? Parsing the JSON? Finding the arrays? Getting all the array values? Eliminating the duplicates? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I only included what i thought was relevant next time I post something i will be sure to give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce all items of category and use a set for unique values. Then render an array of the set.

Method used:

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for concat arrays,
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for getting all categories in one array,
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for getting a new array back.

```js
var array = [{ title: "title one", category: ["dogs", "cats", "pets"] }, { title: "title two", category: ["gold fish", "pets"] }],
    categories = [...new Set(array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a.category), []))];

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: I see you love `Set` in many of your answers

Comment: yes, `Set` comes quite handy for unique values.

Comment: would be nice to see the output for each of the steps

Comment: the problem with `Set` is, you can not really see the datainside of the set, only rendered values in a array. there is no native literal syntax for it, like for arrays or objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map over each post, and get each category.

```
let categories = posts.map((p) => p.category)
```

This might get you duplicate values, since you have `"pets"` in both `category` properties in those objects. To filter out duplicate instances, use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
let categories = posts.map((p) => p.category).filter((c, i, arr) => i == arr.indexOf(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `map()` method and `Set` and spread syntax `...`

```js
var data = [{"title":"title one","category":["dogs","cats","pets"]},{"title":"title two","category":["gold fish","pets"]}]

var result = [...new Set([].concat(...data.map(e => e.category)))]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution

Comment: @vsync Thank you.

Comment: I would even say this is the equivalent of divine poetry in JS world :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that this is an array of objects:

```js
var myArray = [{
    "title": "title one",
    "category": ["dogs", "cats", "pets"]
  },
  {
    "title": "title two",
    "category": ["gold fish", "pets"]
  }
];

var newArray = myArray.map(function(x) {
  return x.category;
});

alert(newArray);
```

You can use the map() function in order to project what you need, title in your case:

Comment: "assuming it's a JSON array" — If you're going to assume that, why doesn't your code start with that?

Comment: why not? see `myArray`

Comment: That's a JavaScript array, not a JSON array.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Still no JSON in it. JavaScript Objects are not JSON objects.

Comment: @Quentin you are right, thank you for the comment!